# When I click the button, function doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery, and I'm trying to figure out why my function doesn't get called when I press the button.  My only clue is that the Firefox Console is showing TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.  I found [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1173013-TypeError-document-getelementbyid%28-%29-is-null) example, which says "document.write will overwrite the entire DOM if it's called after the document has finished being parsed" and that's why it's happening.  I took a look at my code, and I moved the button into my div tag and it's still happening.  I also tried moving the button into it's own div tags.  Compiler didn't seem to like syntax when I tried adding html tags where the button is. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do to fix this.

I'm following [this](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/get-value-selected-checkboxes_cs) example for the function call on button click. Hopefully I'm applying it ok to my project.

This is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.

-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Michele Project</title>
        <link href="css/skins/polaris/polaris.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/demo/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="js/icheck.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.input').iCheck({
                    checkboxClass:'icheckbox_polaris',
                    radioClass:'iradio_polaris',
                    increaseArea:'10%'
                });
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Returns an array with values of the selected (checked) checkboxes in "frm"
            function getSelectedChbox(frm) {
                // JavaScript & jQuery Course - http://coursesweb.net/javascript/
                var selchbox = [];        // array that will store the value of selected checkboxes

                // gets all the input tags in frm, and their number
                var inpfields = frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
                var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;

                // traverse the inpfields elements, and adds the value of selected (checked) checkbox in selchbox
                for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {
                    if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true)
                        selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);
                }
                return selchbox;
            }

            document.getElementById('btntest').onclick = function() {
                var selchb = getSelectedChbox(this.form);
                alert(selchb);
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {list-style-type: none}
            img {padding-right: 20px; float:left}
            #infolist {width:500px}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="skin skin-line">
                <div class="arrows">
                    <div class="top" data-to="skin-flat"></div>
                    <div class="bottom" data-to="skin-polaris"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skin skin-polaris">
                <div class="arrows">
                    <div class="top" data-to="skin-line"></div>
                    <div class="bottom" data-to="skin-futurico"></div>
                </div>
                <h3>Select Items for Column Headings</h3>
                <dl class="clear">
                    <dd class="selected">
                        <div class="skin-section">
                            <h4>Live</h4>
                            <ul class="list">
                                <li>
                                    <input tabindex="21" type="checkbox" id="polaris-checkbox-1">
                                    <label for="polaris-checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input tabindex="22" type="checkbox" id="polaris-checkbox-2" checked>
                                    <label for="polaris-checkbox-2">Checkbox 2</label>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="polaris-checkbox-3" >
                                    <label for="polaris-checkbox-3">Checkbox 3</label>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="polaris-checkbox-4" checked >
                                    <label for="polaris-checkbox-4">Checkbox 4</label>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('.skin-polaris input').iCheck({
                                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
                                radioClass: 'iradio_polaris',
                                increaseArea: '20%'
                            });
                        });
                        </script>
                        //$('#checkbox').prop('checked')
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
            <div id="loading">
                <input type="button" value="Click" id="btntest" /> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you assign the click handler before the element is available in the DOM. To resolve, you should wrap it in a DOM ready function:

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementById('btntest').onclick = function() {
        var selchb = getSelectedChbox(this.form);
        alert(selchb);
    }
});
```

Note: `$(function(){ ... });` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!  I've been looking at this problem since yesterday!  I understand why I've seen the wrapper function now.  I didn't know why it was being used.

Answer (score 1):

You're running `document.getElementById('btntest')` before that element exists. Put this script after your button on the page, not before it:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('btntest').onclick = function() {
        var selchb = getSelectedChbox(this.form);
        alert(selchb);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's a good idea too.  I think I like keeping my functions primarily in the head so that it saves processing time later.  Thank you!!!